# Parsing props.get to int in Jmeter gives "Static method parseInt( java.lang.Integer ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer'"

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do something that should be relatively simple, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I need to store the value inside my property as an integer. I'm trying to do this

Code:

```
log.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + props.get("total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted"));
int total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted = Integer.parseInt(props.get("total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted"));
```

Output:

```
2016/10/12 17:11:22 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>13 
2016/10/12 17:11:22 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServ . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method parseInt( java.lang.Integer ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer' 
2016/10/12 17:11:22 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServ . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method parseInt( java.lang.Integer ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer'
```

This is a property (and not var) because it is getting set in another thread group. But this line keeps giving me the 'Static method parseInt not found...'. All I want is to be able to use that value (13 in this case) inside a for loop. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The error message says that props.get("total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted") is already returning an Integer.  What do you think it's returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

> int total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted = Integer.parseInt(props.get("total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted"));

by:

> int total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted = props.get("total_no_of_backends_getting_targeted");

This is what this message tells you:

> Static method parseInt( java.lang.Integer ) not found in class 'java.lang.Integer'

Which means that Integer.parseInt gets an Integer instead of a String as parameter

Comment: Your solution works perfectly on my home computer. But on my work computer, I get

Comment: You solution works perfectly on my home computer. But on my work computer, I get the following error: 
    2016/10/13 10:07:02 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; import java.util.*; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServ . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Static method parseInt( java.lang.Integer ) not found in class'java.lang.Integer'

Comment: Based on error I would say you're still on old version in your work computer